# how should I concatenate query when using Laravel(MVC) framework?

Tags: php, sql, laravel

```
static function getall($input) {
$where = [];
$params = [];
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM radio_city';
if (isset($input['city']) && $input['city']) {
$where[] = ' city = ?'; // Subsequent additions to $where should specify AND/OR conditional
$params[] = $input['city']; 
}
$sql .= implode(' ', $where); 
$sql .= " GROUP BY city";
return DB::select($sql, $where, $params); 
}
}
```

Here I am using the Laravel(MVC) framework. I am redirecting input form from controller 
so how should i concatenate query with that input. So is this code works or need any modification?

Comment: Maybe http://laravel.com/docs/queries#selects can help

Answer (score 1):

You may try something like this:

```
public static function getAll() {
     $query = DB::table('radio_city');
     if($city = Input::get('city')) {
         $query->where('city', $city);
     }
     return $query->groupBy('city')->get();
}
```

Read more on the [documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/queries). Also look at the [Eloquent](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent) `ORM` and [Scope](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#query-scopes) as well. You should read the documentation first, everything is given there.

Answer (score 0):

The most like is http://laravel.com/docs/queries#joins because Lavarel use a wrapper for the query, it don't use ORM, if you use a framework with ORM (for example Django) or a ORM for PHP (for example Doctrine http://www.doctrine-project.org/ that it is use in Symfony) you can make query more advanced without SQL, but with Laravel you need make it with SQL maked with wrapper of Laravel.